# AWS lambda throws read: connection reset by peer

Tags: go, concurrency, aws-lambda

We are using `AWS Lambda` to process data and generate an useful insight around it.

On using with higher concurrency, the `AWS Lambda` has started throwing

```
read: connection reset by peer
```

On searching, found out that it could be due to higher concurrency execution but the `aws lambda` have a max. concurrency of 1000 and we have utilized only at max around 500 connections. (Using AWS monitoring graph).

We are executing `AWS Lambda` with `API Gateway`

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should see different behavior if you reach concurrency limit on Lambda function:

1. Request does not start lambda code execution. It is terminated before it reaches function. That means that lambda code cannot log any errors.
2. You see 429 HTTP errors in API Gateway

   Error `read: connection reset by peer` means that TCP connection was closed.

It is hard to say what can happen without access to your environment, but check if with increased payload you started to keep open connections longer.

Check MAX lambda execution time in Monitoring. You can increase timeouts or (preferable) find component that cause execution delay and improve it.

Comment: Was using equal value for `database` MaxOpenConnection and MaxIdleConnection in golang. On decreasing the MaxIdleConnection by 5, the error has ceased to exist.

Comment: Database was killing its connection. It is unfortunate you cannot easily say where it happened. Try to add context to these errors when they fired.